# Remove a button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, button, canvas, root

I'm working on a project, when the user answer the question he/she will return back to the page which has the pink button that what it must be..
I'm trying to **remove the pink button** or change its color or at least change the text, but nothing work with me..

This is a sample of my project

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import ttk

def qu1():
    global  r1, r2, r3, r4, Quistion
    Q1.destroy()

    Quistion = Label(root, text='any Q?',fg='black', font=('jost', 16), justify='center')
    Quistion.grid()

    radiover = IntVar()
    r1 = Radiobutton(root, text='a', font = ('Times',12),  variable=radiover, value=1 , command=lambda:[rDesrtoy(),Next()])
    r1.grid()
    r2 = Radiobutton(root, text='b', font = ('Times',12), variable=radiover, value=2, command=lambda:[rDesrtoy(),Next()])
    r2.grid()
    r3 = Radiobutton(root, text='c', font = ('Times',12),  variable=radiover,value=3 ,command=lambda:[rDesrtoy(),Next()])
    r3.grid()
    r4 = Radiobutton(root, text='d', font = ('Times',12), variable=radiover, value=4 , command=lambda:[rDesrtoy(),Next()])
    r4.grid()

def rDesrtoy():
    r1.destroy()
    r2.destroy()
    r3.destroy()
    r4.destroy()
    Quistion.destroy()

def Next():
    global Q1
    Q1 = Button(root, width=15, height=10, bg='#F3C4B7',fg='white', text='1', command=qu1)
    Q1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5, pady=5)

def deleteStart():
    myCanvas.delete('all')
    myCanvas.destroy()

#root
root = Tk()
root.geometry('640x520')

#Canvas 
myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
myCanvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

Start2 = Button(root,width=12,bg='red',command=lambda: [deleteStart(),Next()] ,relief = FLAT)
myCanvas.create_window(220,300, anchor='nw', window=Start2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: to remove `Q1.destroy()`, to change color `Q1['bg'] = 'red'`, to change text `Q1['text'] = "Hello World!"`

Comment: using `import *` is not preferred. Using `[ ]` in `lambda` to run two functions is also not preferred - better create normal function with `deleteStart(),Next()` and assing this function.

Comment: I don't understand your code - you want to remove pink button but your `Radiobutton` runs `Next()` which creates new pink button. maybe create new function which create button with new color or text and use it instead of `Next()`, OR create `def Next(color, text)` and run it with different values.

Comment: if you put widgets on Canvas or in Frame then you can destroy only Canvas or Frame to remove all widgets.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `Q1.destroy()`, to change color `Q1['bg'] = 'red'`, to change text `Q1['text'] = "Hello World!"`.

But I think real problem is to organize it in correct way.

I wouldn't use `[ ]` in `lambda` to run two functions but I would create normal function to run both functions. And I would use some (global) variables to run function with different values.

I would use some global variable to keep all questions as list or dictionary and other variable which show current question - so in every step I could get different question from list - and when it goes back to pink button then I would use it to change text on button.

I put function in order how they are executed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def on_press_start():
    my_canvas.destroy()
    create_next()
    
def create_next():
    global button_1
    
    number = current_question+1

    button_1 = tk.Button(root, width=15, height=10, bg='#F3C4B7', fg='white', text=number, command=create_question)
    button_1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

def create_question():
    global question
    global r1, r2, r3, r4
    
    button_1.destroy()
    
    radiover.set(None) # clear previous selection
    
    data = all_questions[current_question]

    question = tk.Label(root, text=data['question'], fg='black', font=('jost', 16), justify='center')
    question.grid()
    
    answers = data['answers']

    r1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=answers[0], font=('Times',12), variable=radiover, value=0, command=check_answer)
    r1.grid()
    r2 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=answers[1], font=('Times',12), variable=radiover, value=1, command=check_answer)
    r2.grid()
    r3 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=answers[2], font=('Times',12), variable=radiover, value=2, command=check_answer)
    r3.grid()
    r4 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=answers[3], font=('Times',12), variable=radiover, value=3, command=check_answer)
    r4.grid()

def check_answer():
    global current_question
    global points
    
    r1.destroy()
    r2.destroy()
    r3.destroy()
    r4.destroy()
    question.destroy()
    
    selected = radiover.get()
    data = all_questions[current_question]
    print('selected:', data['answers'][selected])
    print('correct :', data['correct'])
    
    if data['answers'][selected] == data['correct']:
        points += 1
    
    current_question += 1
    if current_question < len(all_questions):
        create_next()
    else:
        text = 'Points: {}/{}'.format(points, len(all_questions)) 
        label = tk.Label(root, text=text)
        label.pack()
        print(text)
        print('The End')

# --- main ---
          
all_questions = [
    {'question': 'Any Q', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'next Q', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
]    

current_question = 0

points = 0

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('640x520')

# create only once for all questions
radiover = tk.IntVar(root)

my_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

start = tk.Button(root, text='Start', width=12, bg='red', command=on_press_start ,relief='flat')
my_canvas.create_window(220,300, anchor='nw', window=start)

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

I created other example which display page with buttons to select question. I don't remove buttons (because it changes layout and it doesn't look good) but I disable buttons so you can't click them again (and you can't answer again for the same question)

```
import tkinter as tk

def show_question(n):
    global count_answered

    count_answered += 1
    
    # deactivate button `n`
    buttons[n]['state'] = 'disabled'

    # hide page with buttons
    page_buttons.pack_forget()
    
    # show page with question
    page_question.pack()
    
    # ... set question ...

    q = all_questions[n]
    
    # replace text in existing label
    label_question['text'] = q['question']
    
    label_answer1['text'] = q['answers'][0]
    label_answer2['text'] = q['answers'][1]    
    label_answer3['text'] = q['answers'][2]
    label_answer4['text'] = q['answers'][3]
    
def show_numbers():
    # hide page with question 
    page_question.pack_forget()
    
    # show page with buttons
    page_buttons.pack()
    
    if count_answered >= 12:
        l = tk.Label(page_buttons,text='All answered', bg='red')
        l.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=3, sticky='we')
    
def show_numbers_at_start():
    # hide page with `Start`
    page_start.pack_forget()
    
    show_numbers()
    
# --- main ---

all_questions = [
    None,
    {'question': 'Question 1', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'Question 2', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
    {'question': 'Question 3', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'Question 4', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
    {'question': 'Question 5', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'Question 6', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
    {'question': 'Question 7', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'Question 8', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
    {'question': 'Question 9', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'Question 10', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
    {'question': 'Question 11', 'answers':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'correct': 'a'},
    {'question': 'Question 12', 'answers':['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'correct': '3'},    
]  # I put `None` at index `0` to have questions at indexes `1...9`    

count_answered = 0

# ---

root = tk.Tk()

buttons = [None]  # I put `None` at index `0` to have buttons at indexes `1...9`

# - page with buttons -

page_buttons = tk.Frame(root)
#page_buttons.pack()  # don't show it

for row in range(4):
    for col in range(3):
        number = 1 + (row*3) + col
        button = tk.Button(page_buttons, text=number, command=lambda n=number:show_question(n))
        button.grid(column=col, row=row, sticky='we')
        buttons.append(button)

# - page with question and answers -

page_question = tk.Frame(root)
#page_question.pack()  # don't show it

label_question = tk.Label(page_question, text='') # empty question - I will set it later
label_question.pack()

label_answer1 = tk.Label(page_question, text='')
label_answer1.pack()
label_answer2 = tk.Label(page_question, text='')
label_answer2.pack()
label_answer3 = tk.Label(page_question, text='')
label_answer3.pack()
label_answer4 = tk.Label(page_question, text='')
label_answer4.pack()

button_back = tk.Button(page_question, text='Back', command=show_numbers)
button_back.pack()

# - page with button `Start` -

page_start = tk.Frame(root)
#page_start.pack()  # don't show it

button_start = tk.Button(page_start, text='START', command=show_numbers_at_start) # empty question - I will set it later
button_start.pack()

# - at start show page `Start` -

page_start.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I really appreciate your work, and I'm learning from your notes.. (https://ecdn.teacherspayteachers.com/thumbitem/Free-Number-Cards-1-120-Number-Sense-Kindergarten-First-3359392-1624747921/original-3359392-2.jpg) I need to create buttons like the show in this picture in the second page(pink button) and every button will move the user to a different question, the user will choose randomly the buttons... after answering the question he will return to buttons page.. but the button of answered question will destroy..

Comment: you should describe it in question at start - it better explain what you really need and I wouldn't create my version. I would create `Frame` with all buttons (which I would keep on linst) and later use `pack_forget()` to hide this frame and `pack()` to show it again - and then I would need only destroy (or deactivate) selected button without creating other buttons again. And I would run functions with arguments - like `show_question(1)` - and it would use this argument to access button on list.

Comment: I added new example with page which show buttons to selecte question - and later it disable button to answered qustion.